# Best way to check if value in dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a dictionary of lists like so:

```
dct = {'1': ['hello','goodbye'], '2': ['not here','definitely not here']}
```

What's the fastest way to check if 'hello' is in one of my lists in my dictionary

Comment: `any('hello' in val for val in dct.values())`.

Comment: thanks a lot! if you submit as an answer I can accept and up vote you

Comment: This would be much more efficient if you inverted the data structure. `dct = { 'hello': 1, 'goodbye': 1, 'not here': 2, 'definitely not here': 2 }` -- that way it's a constant-time search, not one that takes longer based on how many items the dictionary has.

Comment: @Charles: Inverting the dictionary isn't free.

Comment: @martineau, sure, but building it in the first place isn't free either. If one knows that's how it's going to be used, maybe you should build it differently in the first place.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry to ask a follow up, but is there an easy way to also get the key or keys of the list or lists which 'hello' appeared in?

Comment: @new_to_coding `[key for key, value in dct.items() if 'hello' in value]`

Comment: @martineau, ...moreover, even if modifying the process by which it's built isn't feasible, one can invert it *once* and search that inverted structure cheaply an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: Yes, you can construct a generator like `(k for k,v in dct.values() if 'hello' in v)`. or a list: `[k for k,v in dct.values() if 'hello' in v]`.

Comment: @martineau: inverting a dictionary is *worst case* as cheap as a single `'hello'` lookup.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if you wish I can answer my own question and give you credit in the answer

Comment: @new_to_coding, ...as an FYI -- if you aren't adding anything to an answer adopted from someone else's comment, it's polite (but not required!) to mark it "community wiki", so that nobody gets credit or rep from it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy alright thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem commented, the easiest way to achieve this is:

```
any('hello' in val for val in dct.values())
```

`any` returns True if any of the values in the given iterable are truthy.

`dct.values()` returns a `dict_values` iterable that yields all the values in a dictionary.

`'hello' in val for val in dct.values()` is a generator expression that yields `True` for each value of `dct` that `'hello'` is in.

If you want to know the keys the string is in, you can do:

```
keys = [key for key, value in dct.items() if 'hello' in value]
```

In your case, `keys` will be `['1']`. If you do this anyways, you can then just call use that list in a boolean context, e.g. `if keys: ...`.